# Setting up a WH_CALLWNDPROC hook prevents WM_HELP propagation in deep hierarchies

Tags: delphi, winapi

When pressing the `F1` key, the win32 API first sends the appropriate key message then sends a `WM_HELP`message to the control that has the focus.
As it does not process it, it gets sent up the parenting chain all the way to the form which reacts to the message.
In Delphi (XE7) this happens because of calls to `CallWindowProc` inside `Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.DefaultHandler`

While this works fine in pretty much all locations inside my applications, there is one place where `WM_HELP` never reaches the top form.
Trying to reproduce it, I came up with a test application that you may find here:

http://obones.free.fr/wm_help.zip

After having built the application and started it, place the focus inside the `In SubLevel` or `Level 1` edits and press F1.
You will see that `WM_HELP` is caught by the form.

Now, if you do the same inside `In SubLevel2` or `Level 15` edits you will see that nothing is logged, the form never sees `WM_HELP`

Tracing in the VCL I found out that for those deep levels, the calls to `CallWindowProc` inside `Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.DefaultHandler` immediately returns on one of the controls in the hierarchy, thus preventing the form from ever receiving the message.

However, I couldn't figure out why the Win32 API code thinks it should not propagate the message anymore, except for one thing: If I remove the `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook, then everything is back to normal.
You can see the effect of disabling it if you uncheck the `Use hook` checkbox.

Now, one will argue that I shouldn't have such deep hierarchies of components, and I agree. However, the structure in the center with two frames inside one another is directly inspired by what's in the application where I noticed the issue.

This means that it can be quite easy to trigger the problem without actually noticing it. Hopefully, in my case, I can remove a few panels and go back below the limit.

But did anyone encounter the situation before? If yes, were you able to solve it? Or is this a known behavior of the Win32 API?

Comment: You need to provide an MCVE. Off site links are not appropriate.

Comment: What's an MCVE?
If that's a "simple example", the zip above contains only sources and is the simplest form I can give because the DFM itself would be pages long.

Comment: You can do a websearch to answer that. You can for sure cut it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by a "Windows kernel stack overflow" that happens if you send window messages recursively. On a 64 bit Windows the kernel stack overflow happens much faster than on a 32 bit Windows.

This bug also caused the VCL to not resize deeply nested controls correctly before it got fixed by changing the recursive AlignControls code to (my) iterative version (more about the stack overflow: http://news.jrsoftware.org/news/toolbar2000/msg07779.html)